# Android Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toolbar

Всем салам. Как сделать toolbar как на фото:

[image: toolbar1]

[image: toolbar2]

Answer (score 2):

Для первого варианта `Toolbar` не получится так кастомизировать, придётся свою разметку руками делать.

Второй вариант можно - меняйте `NavigationIcon`, добавляйте свою разметку в тег `Toolbar` для кнопок посередине и добавляйте `menu` для крайней иконки